# Meaning of XかXないうちに

Tags: grammar, particle-か

> ハリーは試してみた...しかし、**振り上げるかあげないうちに**、老人がひったくってしまった。
> Harry gave it (*the wand*) a try, but no sooner had he raised it than the old man snatched it back.

I read [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1818/%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%8B%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%81%86%E3%81%A1%E3%81%AB-vs-%E6%AC%A1%E7%AC%AC) on XかXないかのうちに with a translation of "within the time span where it is not even clear whether A had happened or not". This seems to neatly describe the situation in my case, but of course the grammar is slightly different.

Is there any difference in meaning/nuance/formality between XかXないうちに and XかXないかのうちに?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. It's just a "sloppy" version, I would say. It's kind of like saying 〜したり〜する instead of 〜したり〜したりする, which is considered more correct.